# Wordpress get_posts function, 1300 lines long

Tags: wp-query, core

I'm just getting started learning about the WordPress Core. WordPress's codebase is the first large codebase that I've looked thoroughly into.

The get_posts method in wp-includes/query.php is 1300 lines long. To me that is huge. Can I expect a lot more of these large functions in the codebase?

Comment: yes that's huge, another one that comes to mind is [`redirect_canonical()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b6d1626613766da413363d2309115561f349c2aa/wp-includes/canonical.php#L41) with few hundred loc.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

To give you some historical perspective WordPress core:

- is relatively *old* code base, code volume tends to grow over time;
- has extreme commitment to backwards compatibility, as result it's extremely rare for code to be removed from core;
- is written in essentially obsolete dialect of PHP version 5.2 (which it remains compatible with), which resulted in monolithic core design and low separation between modules;
- largely ignores code length and complexity metrics for the purposes of development and maintenance.

You don't make it completely clear if you are interested in PHP development in general or WordPress specifically. If you want some experience with *modern* PHP development style you should probably look at different projects, done in more current styles.

Comment: [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/8) is a great choice of framework to learn modern PHP development styles.

Comment: Ok! I'm learning wordpress development, plugins and themes, just curious of the inner workings. Clients seem to like wordpress as their cms.

Comment: @LarryLawless You don't have to know how Wordpress works internally to develop for it, you just have to know where to find API documentation. You can drive a car without the ability to build one yourself.

Comment: @gronostaj it's tangential to the question, but I can't fully agree with that. Shallow level of understanding of _how_ things work inside API is one of unfortunate reasons for low average quality and compatibility of WP code out there.

Comment: @gronostaj I agree with Rarst here. *you just have to know where to find API documentation* Most of the documentation (*codex*) is literally a pile of crap and some info is just totally wrong.

Comment: Sure but it will definitely help. For instance the the_post function. Most documentation about the loop just say that it needs to be present but looking into the code you see that it is what increments to the next post and sets up data for the template tags. I'm reading the professional wordpress book and it encourages that you look into the core a little.